# UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = is not working in swift

Tags: swift

I'm using this code to change tarbar color in swift

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = Color.Black
```

How ever it is not working.
What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put in `viewDidLoad` of your `UITabBarController`

```
tabBar.barTintColor = .black
```

else, if you wanna customize from your viewController put in your `viewWillAppear`:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: I have like about 20 viewControllers, is their a better way?

Comment: then just place in your `UITabBarController`, see the first part of the answer

Comment: It is not working. Neither the first or the second solution. My TarBar stay at White.

Comment: do you need to set the background color? or the tint color of an item?

Comment: sorry,the background one. I can't make it work by using my method(edited)

Comment: Thanks! The second solution is work for me. However the first one is still not working.

Comment: it's pretty strange, I'm using this in my apps :) anyway hope the solution worked

Comment: I change the color in a ViewController, But I need to quit and click in again to make it work. How to reload the ViewController?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194751/discussion-between-coel-wu-and-alastar).

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.requiredColor
    }
}
```

or

```
In storyBoard you can select the tabBar and change the Bartint color
```

Comment: I found solution by other's. Anyway, thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can change color using story board select **tab bar** as circled and from left side choose **Bar Tint** select any color you want

[image]

Comment: Actually I didn't use story board. I like to achieve a function than user can customize their own color for the software.

Comment: then you can achieve it by code as mention in above comments